# Flutter open file from notification without opening the app

Tags: flutter, file, notifications, flutter-local-notification

I'm working on a flutter app which uses `flutter_local_notifications`.
I can create the notifications if the app is closed, but I would like to open a file when tapping on a notification.
At the moment, it is opening the app, when tapping the notif. There is a way to run my function when the app opens, by checking the `didNotificationLaunchApp` and the `payload` from `NotificationAppLaunchDetails`, but this is not what I intended.
Is there a way to open the file directly without opening the app?

I'm using:

```yaml
  flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
  open_file: ^3.2.1
```

Thanks!